# Jquery validate plugin - field that accepts numbers and letters - set maxlength if a number is entered

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I have a field that allows users to search for a store based on either a suburb or a post code.
I am using the Jquery validate plugin to validate the value entered in this field.
Basically, I want to set the maxlength to 4 ONLY if a number is entered. If a suburb is entered there there doesn't need to be a max length.

Any suggestions for the best approach?

Comment: You should really show an attempt at coding this yourself before asking for help.

Comment: I was asking for the best approach to take before taking the time to code a misguided solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a validation rule like

```
var validator = $('#myform').validate({
    rules: {
        search: {
            required: true,
            maxlength: {
                param: 4,
                depends: function(element){
                    var value = $.trim($(element).val());
                    return /^\d+$/.test(value);
                }
            }
        }
    },
    messages: {}
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/YEecd/)